# Hibernate talking to different databases

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, sharding

I need my app to talk to two different databases, which themselves are replicated(using Postgres streaming replication). The reason is that I want to have all the reads happening against one database and writes against the other.

I use hibernate in my application. Is there an out of the box way to achieve this?

-thanks

edit: And yes, please comment on whether what I am trying to achieve makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate supports sharding. See if it helps you: http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html

If you are using spring then I know there is a way to dynamically switch the DataSource. Find more information [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

This is a similar question from stackoverflow: 
[Handling Multiple databases with NHibernate in a single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470751/handling-multiple-databases-with-nhibernate-in-a-single-application)

Also same kind of question in other forum discussion: 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12665

Comment: yes we do use spring. This is interesting, let me explore further ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've simply produced two session factories, and used one for read-only chunks of work and one for read-write chunks of work. I build the read-write factory, then change the configuration to have a different connection provider and add an interceptor to trap any modification attempts and build the second.

One problem with this approach is L2 cache coherence, although that's a general problem with both Hibernate caching and replicated databases.